# creating directory using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mkdir

I need to create a directory using php with write permission...currently am using the following code

```
$folder_name = $this->input->post('foldername', true);

$path = '/home/temp/workspace/My_folder/documents/'.$folder_name;

mkdir($path,'0222');
```

But this is not working...

Comment: Have you check permission's on server ?

Comment: What's not working? The directory is not being created? Permissions are wrong? The permissions arg for mkdir is a number, but you're passing in a string (it should be `..., 0222`, not `..., '0222'`. Does your webserver user have permissions to modify the `../documents/` directory? Does it have access to ALL of the directories in that $path? All it takes is to fail is NOT having rights to just one of them.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your application (Apache probably) have the right to write in that directory? Does the directory exist?

try this maybe:

```
$path = '/home/temp/workspace/My_folder/documents/'.$folder_name;
mkdir($path, 0222, $recursive=true);
```

Comment: 0222, Is this for Write permission?

Comment: Check this function for type of permissions ->http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: change to mkdir($path, 0222); and check the user's permissions for creating a directory.